# Определить: сколько раз последовательность меняет знак?

Tags: python

```
import random

x=0
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(2):
        a=random.randint(-15,15)
        print(a, end=' ')
        if a<0 : x+=1
    print()

    print("Отрицательных чисел:", x)
```

До чего смог допетрил, так и не могу придумать как сделать что-бы считывало то, сколько раз последовательность случайных чисел меняла знак

Comment: Первоначально залил кривой код, исправил.

Comment: Смена знака -- это уже производная! А вообще вам просто надо хранить предыдущее значение.

Comment: А с нулем как быть? Какой у него знак?

Comment: Какой хотите. Это условность, которую надо просто обозначить. По идее надо считывать следующее значение и выбирать его... Хе-х, тут надо немного подумать. В общем, нарисуйте на картинке. Его знак будет по предыдущему легко вычисляться. Если был минус, то плюс, и наоборот.

Comment: Я полагаю нуль можно просто проигнорировать в этом случае ;D

Comment: @user234223, у вас задача академическая или практическая?

Comment: Практическая, недавно начал учить Python

Comment: В общем, функция знака числа имеет **три** значения. Я погорячился выше с условностями.

Comment: @0andriy: количество нулей у функции это не производная.

Comment: @jfs, количество нулей не определяет **смену знака** функции.

Comment: @0andriy верно, количество смен знака =  количество нулей - нули с экстремумами

Comment: @jfc,нулей производной данной функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше разделить код, который генерирует случайные числа, от кода, который считает перемены знака:

```
def count_sign_reversals(numbers):
    it = iter(numbers)
    sign = next(it, 0) < 0
    count = 0
    for n in it:
        if sign is not (n < 0):
            count += 1
            sign = not sign # sign changed
    return count
```

Пример:

```
>>> import random
>>> count_sign_reversals(random.randint(-15, 15) for _ in range(7*2))
8  # one of possible answers
>>> count_sign_reversals([1, -2, 3])
2
>>> count_sign_reversals([1, -2])
1
>>> count_sign_reversals([-1, 2])
1
>>> count_sign_reversals([-1, -2])
0
>>> count_sign_reversals([1, 2])
0
>>> count_sign_reversals([1])
0
>>> count_sign_reversals([])
0
```

Если хочется `0` и `-0.0` различать, то можно отфильтровать через [`math.copysign()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.copysign):

```
from functools import partial

numbers = map(partial(math.copysign, 1), numbers)
```

Comment: Нулей добавьте несколько

Comment: Это никак не влияет. sign в коде  это signbit (определяет является ли число отрицательным и как имя подсказывает может только два значения принимать).

Comment: так это ограничение архитектуры. В троичной системе счисления и соответствующих компьютерах всё соответствует математическим представлениям.

Comment: причём здесь архитектура. Не нужны троичные компьютеры, чтобы разбить последовательность в соответствии с функцией, возвращающей три значения. К примеру, [подход из @MaxU ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620012/23044), вполне рабочий для целых чисел: `len(list(groupby(lst, key=lambda n: -1 if n < 0 else 1 if n else 0))) - (len(lst) > 0)` (похожее определение `numpy.sign()` использует). Это не значит, что это "лучше" определение--просто другое и может быть полезным для каких то задач.

Answer (score 1):

Если два числа имеют разные знаки - их произведение отрицательно

В этом смысле 0 обрабатывается корректно, он не меняет знак независимо от того положительно или отрицательно предыдущее число, т.к. сам ноль знака не имеет. Правда неясно, меняет ли знак последовательность `(-1, 0, +1)`. С одной стороны ни одна пара соседних элементов не имеет разного знака, с другой - есть и положительные и отрицательные элементы.

```
def count(l):
    prev = 0
    r = 0
    for value in l:
        r += 1 if prev * value < 0 else 0
        prev = value if value != 0 else prev
    return r

print count([-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, -1]) # -> 4
```

Так последовательность (-1,0,+1) даст результат 1. Если внутри цикла вместо `prev = value if value != 0 else prev` написать `prev = value` - посчитает число пар соседних элементов с разными знаками. (Ни пара 0, -1 ни пара 0, +1 разного знака не имеют). Вообще вместо `prev * value < 0` можно написать явно `(prev > 0 and value < 0) or (prev < 0 and value > 0)` будет просто более громоздко. Зато можно будет считать 0 и положительным и отрицательным меняя соответствующие неравенства на >=.

Comment: для `float` может сломаться из-за потери точности или таких вещей как `-0.0`. [Можно через `math.copysign()` фильтровать в таких случаях.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620184/23044)

Comment: Значение функии *знак числа* не бинарно, а тернарно!

Comment: @0andriy Это кто сказал? 0 не имеет никакого знака, ни +, ни -, ни какого-либо другого.

Comment: @jfs -0.0 - нормально дает `False` при сравнении и >0 и <0. Для двух очень маленьких чисел произведение действительно может быть равно 0.

Comment: @andy.37 "нормально" для разных определений разное. Главное определиться какое определение используется. Вы не обязаны следовать определению из math.copysign()

Comment: @jfs У меня в консоли -0.0 == 0 дает True, -0.0 > 0 -> False, -0.0 < 0 -> False. Именно такое поведение я считаю правильным. Если использовать произведение, проблема будет с последовательностью `(-1e-300, 1e-300)`

Comment: @andy.37: посмотрите на заголовок вопроса. Вопрос о смене знака, а не сравнении с нулём. Что такое знак можно по разному определять: [в моём ответе это signbit (n < 0)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620184/23044), `math.copysign()` может различать между `-0.0` и `0`, `numpy.sign()` это вообще трёхзначная функция

Comment: @jfs я говорю о точке зрения *математики*. С ее точки зрения, числа -0.0 - *не существует*. И даже с точки зрения Питона, -0.0  == 0. Но в целом, это конечно вопрос философский == не имеющий ответа. )))

Comment: @andy.37: вы можете в своём ответе какие угодно определения знака использовать, но не нужно за математику говорить. что по вашему слово `math` в `math.copysign` означает? Вы думаете философы придумали floating point? или реализовали numpy?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52631/discussion-between-andy-37-and-jfs).

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой, да и надежный путь - наивное решение со счетчиком и циклом. Но это не наш метод. Для начала текст, потом код.

Возьмем вот такой массив как пример: `[-3, -4, 5, -5, 0, 3, -3]` и оставим вместо самих чисел только их знак: `1` для положительных, `-1` для отрицательных: `[-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1]`. Теперь будем брать последовательно два рядом стоящих числа (их знака). Вот так будет выглядеть последовательность:

```
-3, -4 (-1, -1); 
-4, 5 (-1, 1); 
5, -5 (1, -1); 
-5, 0 (-1, 1); 
0, 3 (1, 1); 
3, -3 (1, -1).
```

Таких пар чисел будет ровно `len(list) - 1`, т.е. длина списка минус 1. Представьте, что все числа положительны. Тогда сумма всех пар знаков (т.е. единиц) будет равна `(len(list) - 1) * 2`. Хорошо, если вы не просто поверите на слово, а проверите данный тезис. Каждая пара чисел с разными знаками уменьшает сумму на 2. Обозначим сумму этих пар знаков как `summ` и исходя из всего вышесказанного количество смен знаков будет равно `((len(list) - 1) * 2 - summ) / 2`. Распишем сумму как сумму элементов массива с индексами: 
summ := |a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>| + |a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>| + |a<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub>| + |a<sub>3</sub> + a<sub>4</sub>| + |a<sub>4</sub> + a<sub>5</sub>| + |a<sub>5</sub> + a<sub>6</sub>|, где `|...|` - это модуль числа. На этом в общем-то и все:

```
import random
# Все, что касается знаков спихиваем на библиотеку
# Ибо можно попасть на всякие нехорошие вещи типа -0.0, nan, -nan и т.д.
# Однако copysign вычисляет в процессе арктангенс(!!!) от числа и нельзя сказать, что
# это очень быстро. Для ультра быстроты можно поиграть с битовыми сдвигами
from math import copysign

LIST_LEN = 7

target_list = [random.randint(-15, 15) for _ in range(LIST_LEN)]
only_ones_list = [copysign(1, element) for element in target_list]

summ = 0
for i in range(len(only_ones_list) - 1):
    summ += abs(only_ones_list[i] + only_ones_list[i + 1])

sign_change_count = ((len(only_ones_list) - 1) * 2 - summ) / 2

print(target_list)
print(only_ones_list)
print(sign_change_count)

>>> [-6, 12, -3, -11, -12, -13, 7]
>>> [-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
>>> 3.0
```

Список из знаков можно не составлять, конечно же, а сразу пройти по исходному.

Теперь самое сложное - чем данное может быть полезным. Во-первых, никаких рассуждений о знаковости нуля или nan или еще чего угодно. Мы используем стандартную функцию и не паримся. Теоретически можно обойтись совсем без условных операторов (внутри abs и copysign) - получение знака и модуль числа можно попробовать вычислить хитрыми битовыми операциями. Также теоретически сложение быстрее, чем умножение, однако разница будет заметна на больших массивах.

Comment: если последовательность пустая `[]`, то ответ должен быть `0` (нет перемен знака), а не `-1` как у вас в коде.

Comment: 0 не имеет знака.

Comment: @0andriy, это, конечно, так, но с точки зрения математики. Однако, есть технический стандарт и при написании программ программист _должен_ ему следовать. Когда речь идет про нули и прочее, то стандарт называется [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), [Signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero). Можно считать это костылем (и зря), но игнорировать и закрывать глаза с мантрой "не существует" не стоит.

Comment: @m9_psy, а вы поняли о чём там вообще речь?