# Подсчитать количество перемен знака в последовательности целых чисел

Tags: c++

Написал программу, которая считает количество смены знака в последовательности чисел.
Можно ли ее написать без использования массива.. только через цикл?
Спасибо

```
int N, count = 0;
  cout << "Количество чисел" << endl;
  cin >> N;

int arr[N];
      cout << "Введите числа" << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      cin >> arr[i];
   for (int i = 0; i < N -1 ; i++)
 if (arr[i] < 0 && arr[i+1] >= 0 || arr[i] >= 0 && arr[i+1] < 0)

 count++;
 cout << count << endl;
```

Comment: Можно. Достаточно "помнить" знак предыдущего числа

Comment: Подскажите как это сделать. Только начал учить, сложновато

Comment: Вам подсказать как переменную новую создать? В вашем коде уже есть создание переменных.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Определить: сколько раз последовательность меняет знак?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/620006/23044) (обратите внимание, что такое перемена знака может быть разным в разных контекстах)

Comment: На C#/LINQ: `seq.Select(Math.Sign).Pairwise((p, n) => p != n).Count(v => v)`. Функция Pairwise [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/755769/10105).

Comment: @VladD `sum(1 for p, n in pairwise(x<0 for line in sys.stdin for x in map(int, line.split())) if p != n)` [пример](https://ideone.com/WnTT4n)

Comment: @VladD или проще: `sum(1 for _ in groupby(signbits)) - 1`  [пример](https://ideone.com/O3bZ3Q)

Comment: @jfs: Странно, у нас group by работает по-другому, оно делает глобальную группировку, и получится максимум три группы. (Если я правильно понял ваше решение.)

Comment: @VladD groupby() режет ввод на группы одинаковых значений, которые подряд идут. Количество перемен знака это количество групп минус один (перемена между группами, как верёвку резать: количество разрезов на один меньше количества кусков). Пример по ссылке показывает что всё работает.

Comment: @jfs: Угу, я так и подумал. В LINQ `GroupBy` производит глобальные группы, как в SQL. То есть, делит на группы, содержащие _все_ одинаковые значения, а не только идущие подряд. В этом различие.

Answer (score 1):

Трансляция [решения на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620184/23044) на С++:

```
template<class InputIterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
count_sign_reversals(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
  typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type count = 0;
  if (first == last)
    return count;
  bool sign = *first++ < 0;
  for ( ; first != last; ++first)
    if (sign != (*first < 0)) {
      sign = !sign;
      ++count;
    }
  return count;
}
```

Использовать [можно так](https://ideone.com/hOgN7z):

```
int main() {
  std::istream_iterator<int> numbers(std::cin), eof;
  std::cout << count_sign_reversals(numbers, eof) << std::endl;
}
```

Использование [`count_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), убирает явный цикл, но не делает код заметно проще здесь:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  std::istream_iterator<int> numbers(std::cin), eof;
  auto count = std::count_if(numbers, eof, [](int n) {
      static bool sign = n < 0;
      bool changed_sign = (sign != (n < 0));
      if (changed_sign) sign = !sign;
      return changed_sign;
    });
  std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/mBZgLY).